# Unity Why is this trigger not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make a door in Unity C# and I got it working for the most part, what doesn't seem to work is letting the player go through while the player is still inside the trigger when standing still. When I move when in the trigger the door works but when I stand still it doesn't, also teleporting the player seems to be instant as soon as the open door button is pressedwhich I do know how to fix.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BaseDoorScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float NeededKeyNumber;
public float TpDelay;

public bool CanOpen;
public bool NeedsKey;
public bool Playerisatdoor;

//Door in the hallway
public GameObject Entrancedoor;
public bool isbossdoor;
public bool playerisentering;
//Door in the bossroom
public GameObject ExitBossdoor;


public GameObject SpawnBossRoom;
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Playerisatdoor = true;
        Debug.Log("Player Is Here");
        //collision.transform.position = ExitBossdoor.transform.position;
        if (CanOpen == true && Playerisatdoor == true)
        {
            var PlayerKey = collision.GetComponent<KeyScript>().KeyNumber;
            if (NeedsKey == true)
            {
                //if (Input.GetButton("EnterDoor"))
                //{
                    if (PlayerKey == NeededKeyNumber)
                    {

                        if (isbossdoor == false)
                        {
                            collision.transform.position = ExitBossdoor.transform.position;
                            SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        if (isbossdoor == true)
                        {
                            collision.transform.position = Entrancedoor.transform.position;
                            SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(false);
                        }
                    }
                //}
            }
            if (NeedsKey == false)
            {
                if ( playerisentering == true
                    //Input.GetButton("EnterDoor") || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)
                    )
                {
                    Debug.Log("ButtonPressed");
                    if (isbossdoor == false)
                    {
                        collision.transform.position = ExitBossdoor.transform.position;
                        SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(true);
                    }
                    if (isbossdoor == true)
                    {
                        collision.transform.position = Entrancedoor.transform.position;
                        SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Playerisatdoor = false;
    }
}
private void Update()
{
    if(Playerisatdoor == true)
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("EnterDoor") || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            StartCoroutine("TeleportPlayer");
        }
        else
        {
            playerisentering = false;
        }
    }
}
public IEnumerator TeleportPlayer ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(TpDelay);
    playerisentering = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
}
```

Comment: One point is that you should move `Playerisatdoor = true` to `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Basically all the one time check part should be there. For the teleport, whats `TpDelay` set to?

Comment: The not working when standing still part has to do with the rigidbody settings or the character controller (if you use one of the assets) I think. For the settings, put `Sleeping Mode` to `Never Sleep`.

Comment: `if (NeedsKey == true)` simplifies to `if (NeedsKey)`, then `if (NeedsKey == false)` simplifies to `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops forgot to mention that I fixed this situation a while ago, I think I will just put in the script that I used to help anyone with a similar problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BaseDoorScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float NeededKeyNumber;
public float TpDelay;

public bool CanOpen;
public bool NeedsKey;
public bool Playerisatdoor;

//Door in the hallway
public GameObject Entrancedoor;
public bool isbossdoor;
public bool playerisentering;
//Door in the bossroom
public GameObject ExitBossdoor;


public GameObject SpawnBossRoom;
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Playerisatdoor = true;
        Debug.Log("Player Is Here");
        //collision.transform.position = ExitBossdoor.transform.position;
        if (CanOpen == true && Playerisatdoor == true)
        {
            var PlayerKey = collision.GetComponent<KeyScript>().KeyNumber;
            if (NeedsKey == true)
            {
                //if (Input.GetButton("EnterDoor"))
                //{
                    if (PlayerKey == NeededKeyNumber)
                    {

                        if (isbossdoor == false)
                        {
                            collision.transform.position = ExitBossdoor.transform.position;
                            SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        if (isbossdoor == true)
                        {
                            collision.transform.position = Entrancedoor.transform.position;
                            SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(false);
                        }
                    }
                //}
            }
            if (NeedsKey == false)
            {
                if ( playerisentering == true
                    //Input.GetButton("EnterDoor") || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)
                    )
                {
                    Debug.Log("ButtonPressed");
                    if (isbossdoor == false)
                    {
                        collision.transform.position = ExitBossdoor.transform.position;
                        SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(true);
                    }
                    if (isbossdoor == true)
                    {
                        collision.transform.position = Entrancedoor.transform.position;
                        SpawnBossRoom.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Playerisatdoor = false;
    }
}
private void Update()
{
    if(Playerisatdoor == true)
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("EnterDoor") || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            StartCoroutine("TeleportPlayer");
        }
        else
        {
            playerisentering = false;
        }
    }
}
public IEnumerator TeleportPlayer ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(TpDelay);
    playerisentering = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
}




// RoomKey Numbers:
/* 



*/
```